# How to attach an ENI to CentOS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos7

I wish to attach a ENI to an instance. While doing this for Amazon Linux AMI, it simply works. While doing the same for an instance spinned up from CentOS 7 AMI and when I do an ifconfig within the instance, I see only eth0 interface but no eth1. Although from console it shows as eth0 and eth1 attached.

Comment: I would start by reading this thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=84340

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me with CentOS7.2

```
sudo cp /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
```

Replace eth0 with eth1. Leave DHCP as is, even if you've given the ENI a static IP.

Answer (score -1):

**To create an elastic network interface using the console:**
1. Open the Amazon EC2 console.
2. In the navigation pane, **choose Network Interfaces.**
3. Choose **Create Network Interface.**
4. In the **Create Network Interface** dialog box, provide the following information for the elastic network interface and choose **Yes, Create.**
a. For **Description**, enter a descriptive name.
b. For **Subnet**, select the subnet. Note that you can't move the elastic network interface to another subnet after it's created, and you can only attach the interface to instances in the same Availability Zone.
c. For **Private IP**, enter the primary private IP address. If you don't specify an IP address, we'll select an available private IP address from within the selected subnet.
d. For **Security groups**, select one or more security groups.
**To create an elastic network interface using the command line**
`aws ec2 create-network-interface --subnet-id subnet-9d4a7b6c --description "my network interface" --groups sg-903004f8 --private-ip-address 10.0.2.17`

Comment: Its not about creating an ENI, but attaching an ENI to centos instance reliably.

Comment: Go to EC2>Network Interface select your newly created **Network Interface** click **Attach** & select **Instance ID**.

Comment: The answer is irrelevant to the question being asked.