# EC2 host unreachable on secondary private address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have a subnet(s1) in my VPC.Say subnet1 at the range of 10.1.1.0/24,I have 3 machines(m1,m2,m3) launched which has three private address(p1,p2,p3).m1 also has an elastic IP address to reach the machine from Internet.I just need an secondary private address(p4) that need to be associated with (m2 or m3) one at a time.P4 is choosen manually(just an unused address in same subnet) for load balancing stuffs.
The secondary ip association is coordinated by scripts so (p4) wont be bound to two machines at a time.

I am binding that p4 by `ifconfig eth0:1 p4 netmask mask up`
And I publish it by `send_arp`.
This same setup works in my local setup.But I can't made to work in AWS environment.
Even after calling send_arp done `arp -a` shows that mac address is incomplete.
I need to access m2 or m3 by secondary private Ip address from m1
Is that even possible in the AWS environment?

Comment: `P4 is chosen manually` nope, you can assign an additional internal IP address using AWS configuration, but not manually. I mean - you can assign it, but as far I know the VPC will drop any traffic

Answer (score 1):

In AWS every private IP address is attached to an ENI (Elastic Network Interface). When we create an EC2 instance, AWS assigns an ENI to our instance, but if we want to have multiple IP addresses, we can create our own ENIs and assign them to our EC2 instance.

In order to create an ENI, we can go in the AWS console to `EC2` -> `Network & Security` (left tab) -> `Network Interfaces` -> `Create Network Interface`. After a network interface is created, it can be assigned manually, or your case you can use a script to assign it to one your EC2 instances (more info in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html)).

After an ENI is assigned to an instance, we should be able to see it inside the instance by simple running an `ifconfig -a`. There is no need for other `ifconfig` adjustments (at least in case of Amazon Linux 2, I did not try for other distros).

Comment: can we make this inside machine via shell script?

Comment: Yes, using the AWS cli [attach-network-interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/attach-network-interface.html) command and [create-network-interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-network-interface.html) command.

Comment: `eth1: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether xxxxxxxxxxx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

` can't find the ip address after I attached it to instance

Comment: I am using centos server.

Comment: Probably this may help with CentOS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894073/how-to-attach-an-eni-to-centos

Comment: That doesn't work either.Even though it is not straight forward as `ifconfig` step.I think its time consuming process that is unacceptable in production mode.Any way thanks for ur help.